# For loop and its reverse based on if-condition/ternary operation in Oracle

Tags: oracle, plsql

In Oracle, I have the following *almost* identical SQL in an `if-else` block of a stored procedure:

```
  if v_endsid = '15' then 
    FOR i IN 1..v_num LOOP --loop around the number from the beginning
      v_item := TRIM(SUBSTR(v_str, (i - 1) * 12 + 1, 12)); --now this is the evaluated item
      if v_item = TRIM(cursorElement.ITEM) then --this is the time to break
        break;
      end if;
    END LOOP;                        
  else 
    FOR i IN REVERSE 1..v_num LOOP --loop around the number from the last
      v_item := TRIM(SUBSTR(v_str, (i - 1) * 12 + 1, 12)); --now this is the evaluated item
      if v_item = TRIM(cursorElement.ITEM) then --this is the time to break
        break;
      end if;
    END LOOP;                        
  end if;
```

As you can see, the only difference between the SQL in the `if` and `else` blocks is the `FOR` loop. One is a forward for loop, another is a reversed (backward) for loop.

Is there any way to combine the block? I am trying this:

```
FOR i IN (case when v_endsid = '15' then 1..v_num else REVERSE 1..v_num end) LOOP
  v_item := TRIM(SUBSTR(v_str, (i - 1) * 12 + 1, 12)); --now this is the evaluated item
  if v_item = TRIM(cursorElement.ITEM) then --this is the time to break
    break;
  end if;
END LOOP;
```

But it gives me compilation error in the `1..v_num`:

> Found: '..' Expecting: END -or- ELSE -or- WHEN -or- OR -or- AND -or-
>   BETWEEN IN LIKE LIKE2 LIKE4 LIKEC MEMBER SUBMULTISET -or- ! != < <= <>
>   = > >= ^ ^= IS NOT ~

Comment: May be you have a basic `LOOP.. EXIT WHEN... END LOOP;` and customize the iteration. The change you expect in `FOR LOOP` is not possible.

Comment: @MaheswaranRavisankar I see... so we cannot do that using `FOR LOOP` (too bad :() OK, thanks for the comment. In that case, I will try to do it using basic `LOOP`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The final solution I adapt is by using basic `LOOP` and some ternary operations:

```
i := case when v_endsid = '15' then 1 else v_num end; --evaluates from front or back depending on the case
Loop
    v_item := TRIM(SUBSTR(v_str, (i - 1) * 12 + 1, 12)); --now this is the evaluated item        
    --other queries                
    i := i + (case when v_endsid = '15' then 1 else -1 end);
    exit when i = 0 or i = v_num + 1; --exceeds the elements
end loop;
```

This, I think, is a fairly neat working replacement for the original SQL

Answer (score 1):

There is no way of dynamically changing the direction of the for loop. The only thing you can do here if you want to combine the two blocks is to use a basic loop

```
  if v_endsid = '15' then 
     i := 1;
     reverse := false;
  else
     i := v_num;
     reverse := true;
  end if;
  LOOP --loop around the number from the beginning
      v_item := TRIM(SUBSTR(v_str, (v_num - 1) * 12 + 1, 12)); --now this is  the evaluated item
      if v_item = TRIM(cursorElement.ITEM) then --this is the time to break
        break;
      end if;
     if reverse = true then 
        if i = 1 then 
           exit;
        else
           i := i - 1; 
     else 
        if i = v_num then 
           exit;
        else
           i := i + 1; 
        end if;
     end if;
  END LOOP;
```

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate the sample answer.

Answer (score 0):

How about the another way round ? Instead of manipulating the loop condition encapsulate the code evaluating the break condition into a function that can be called from the different loops.

```
declare
  v_reverse constant boolean := true;
  -- your parameters and break rule can be arbitrary complex, mine is simple
  -- as this is just a demonstration
  function break(i in pls_integer) return boolean is
  begin
    return 13 = i;
  end;
begin
  if v_reverse
  then
    for i in reverse 1 .. 15
    loop
      dbms_output.put_line(i);
      exit when break(i);
    end loop;
  else
    for i in 1 .. 15
    loop
      dbms_output.put_line(i);
      exit when break(i);
    end loop;
  end if;
end;
/
```